# TYPO3/Typoscript : trim value failed

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

This is my typoscript code :

```
lib.test.renderObj = COA
lib.test.renderObj.10 = TEXT
lib.test.renderObj.10.stdWrap.field = header
lib.test.renderObj.10.stdWrap.case = lower
lib.test.renderObj.10.stdWrap.trim = 1
lib.test.renderObj.10.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="element">|</div>
```

The header field is well received, letters have been lowercased and the field is well wrapped by a  element. The only problem is that i can't make the TRIM properties effective. I also tried to use the search/replace properties -> no success.

Any clue ? :)

Comment: Maybe due to the forgotten `.`? ;)

Comment: :) @ThomasLöffler Sorry, my copy/paste was false : the missing point isn't in my live typoscript. Problem is still ongoing

Comment: Any idea ? I can't understand what's wrong ...

Comment: Your TypoScript works fine in my test case. What exactly is the content of your header field where it is not working? (my test case was "     aEOu     " which became "<div class="element">aeou</div>")

Comment: The field header = "MY CUSTOM APP", I'd like to get "mycustomapp". With the code above this i what I got : "my custom app"... maybe I would try to use an alternative like .replace ? How to do ?

Comment: http://nsa39.casimages.com/img/2017/10/11/171011044939916636.png

(The replace + search method didn't work neither ... )

Comment: trim removes the whitespaces at the beginning and the end of the string, not inside of it.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler Oh ! my bad, i was expecting to remove all the whitespaces off the field value. Do you know how to make it, maybe wiith replace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search and replace since 4.6. The documentation you can find here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/Functions/Replacement/

```
lib.test.renderObj.10.stdWrap.replacement {
    10 {
        search = # #
        replace = 
        useRegExp = 1
    }
}
```

Don't know if the replace is really working, can't test it.

Comment: Great =) Your snippet resolved my issue. I had already implement the replacement method but without the "useRegExp" attribute. Thank you so much man !